# Capturar id de rota resource laravel com parâmetro extra

Tags: php, laravel

Possuo a seguinte rota do tipo resource:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'processos' ,'namespace' => 'Processos', 'middleware' => 'processo_exists'], function () {

    // Andamentos
    Route::resource('{processo_id}/andamentos', 'AndamentosController');
});
```

Quando acesso a url:

```
site.com.br/processos/1/andamentos/9
```

O método `show` recebe um parâmetro `$id`, só que ele mostra o id do processo (que é o número 1), e não o 9, sendo que o nome do parâmetro para o processo é `{processo_id}`, o `$id` não é o nome padrão para o resource?

Comment: Não pode ser `resource` nesse caso, tem que ser configurado cada método para cada rota, e o nome é o paramento que deve constar no método. Porque realmente o resource tem um padrão e a sua rota não está no padrão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisa especificar tambem o parametro para o id no final

`Route::resource('{processo_id}/andamentos/{id}', 'AndamentosController');`

ai no metodo show provavelmente vai ter algo assim

```
function show(Request $res, $processoId, $id){
    echo $processoId;
    echo $id;
}
//site.com.br/processos/1/andamentos/9
//nessa url o trecho acima deve mostar os valores 1 e 9
```

Para mais informacoes veja os docs do Laravel sobre [routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing)

Comment: Ele deu um erro porque já existe um {id} implícito, mas passando os parâmetros para o método funciona ok